# VB.Net, How to get the String Value

Tags: string, vb.net, function

Here is my function to normal string to alpha numeric for requirement

```
    Public Function ToModern(_cond$)
      Dim _A% = 0 : Dim _B% = 0, _C% = 0
      Dim _mdSt$ = ""
      _A% = _cond$.Count(Function(x) x = "A")
      _B% = _cond$.Count(Function(x) x = "B")
      _C% = _cond$.Count(Function(x) x = "C")
      _mdSt = $"{_A%}A{_B%}B{_C}C"

     Return _mdSt$
   End Function
```

working fine and answer is

```
    Public Function Test()
       Trace.WriteLine(ToModern("AAABBBCCC")) '3A3B3C
       Trace.WriteLine(ToModern("CCCCBBBAAA")) '3A3B4C
       Trace.WriteLine(ToModern("BBAACCCC")) '2A2B4C
    End Function
```

ToModern("AAABBBCCC")) '3A3B3Cis correct but the second one want to like 3C3B3A instead the result how to achieve this

Comment: What should `"AABBAA"` give?

Comment: result expected 3A2B :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Function ToModern(_cond$)
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    For Each s As String In _cond$.ToList().Distinct()
        result = result & (From c In _cond$.ToList() Where c = s Select c).Count().ToString() & s
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: thank you @Wojciech Wojtulewski